# field of type link in admin form is not rendering value

Tags: magento-1.7, admin, catalog, blocks, forms

My class extends from `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Form`, which has declaration for `_prepareForm` method with code for `myfield` as follows

```
  $fieldset->addField('myElementId', 'link', array(
      'label'     => 'myLabel',
      'href' => 'http://magento.stackexchange.com',
      'value'  => 'myElementValue'
    ));
```

This field is rendering all except `value` (i.e, myElementValue).

Can any one help me with this?

Billions of Thanks in Advance

EDIT:

My class name - MyNameSpace_MyModule_Block_Adminhtml_MyBlockGroup_ClassExtendingFormContainer_Tab_Form

This class defines the _prepareForm function as follows:

```
 protected function _prepareForm()
 {
       $form = new Varien_Data_Form();
       $this->setForm($form);
       $fieldset = $form->addFieldset('someElementId',array('key'=>'value'));          

      $fieldset->addField('myElementId', 'link', array(
                      'label'     => 'myLabel',
             'href' => 'http://magento.stackexchange.com/',
              'value'  => 'myElementValue',
            ));

      $fieldset->addField('myElementId2', 'text', array(
                    'label' => 'myLabel2',
                    'name' => 'myElementId2',
             ));

  $dateFormatIso = Mage::app()->getLocale()->getDateTimeFormat(Mage_Core_Model_Locale::FORMAT_TYPE_SHORT);
      $fieldset->addField('myElementId3', 'date', array(
                     'name'   => 'myElementId3',
                     'label'  => 'myLabel3',
                     'width'=>"100px",
                     'image'  => $this->getSkinUrl('images/grid-cal.gif'),
                     'input_format' => Varien_Date::DATE_INTERNAL_FORMAT,
                     'format'       => $dateFormatIso,
                     'time' => true, 
        ));

     if ( Mage::registry('SomeRegistrySetinCurrentControllerAction') )
     {
       $form->setValues(Mage::registry('SomeRegistrySetinCurrentControllerAction')->getData());
 }

 return parent::_prepareForm();
 }
```

It is rendering date, text fields in the form but not link.

Comment: Could you show us full class declaration.

Comment: Your code is working fine on my end. We probably need a bit more/precise details. What happens when you change `'link'` to `'text'`? Will the value show in the text box?

Comment: @Homidjonov, i have edited my Question accordingly.

Comment: @Dan, No, when i replace 'link' with 'text' value is rendered in TextField(i.e, TF is empty).

Comment: @basha Your code is working fine except for `form->addFieldset(` should be `$form->addFieldset`, but I suspect that is just a typo here. So the only explanation, is to check your real code and make sure you don't have a typo somewhere. Like maybe, you have typed `valeu` instead of `value`.

Comment: @Homidjonov, my mistake of not showing the code completely earlier. Now it is working.Thanks alot for your consideration.

Comment: @Dan, As you said from the starting it should be working in my machine too, unless i work on the **$form->setValues** method, at the end its my mistake for not showing this earlier, I value the time spent on my issue.Thanks for that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code works (almost) correctly.
The value of the link field is not shown because it is overwritten by 
`$form->setValues(...)`.
Here is how `Varien_Data_Form::setValues()` works

```
public function setValues($values)
    {
        foreach ($this->_allElements as $element) { //for each element in the form
            if (isset($values[$element->getId()])) {//if there is a value in the values for the element set the value of that element.
                $element->setValue($values[$element->getId()]);
            }
            else {//if there is no value for the element set its value to null.
                $element->setValue(null);
            }
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

I recommend using `$form->addValues(...)`; this one does not set to null the missing values in the parameter passed to it.